# different results for standard form and functional form of data.table assigne-by-reference `:=`

Tags: r, data.table, assign

There seems to be a minor difference between data.tabel's assignment by reference := in the standard to the functinal form.

Standard form coerces RHS to vector, the functional form does not.
A detail, but not documented as I believe.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = c('a','b','c'))
v <- c('A','B','C')
l <- list(v)

all.equal(copy(dt)[, new := v], copy(dt)[, `:=` (new = v)])
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(copy(dt)[, new := l], copy(dt)[, `:=` (new = l)])
# [1] "Datasets have different column modes. First 3: new(character!=list)"

copy(dt)[, new := l][]
#    a new
# 1: a   A
# 2: b   B
# 3: c   C

copy(dt)[, `:=` (new = l)][]
#    a   new
# 1: a A,B,C
# 2: b A,B,C
# 3: c A,B,C
```

This is a major Edit of how I asked this question originally.

Comment: Fwiw, you should use `X[Y, on=, col]` not `X[Y, on=][, col]` since the latter creates the join for all columns before selecting the single column needed.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for the hint. Join inherited scope. I have edited the question to make the issue clearer.

Comment: I think this is happening because  the RHS should always be a list of column vectors, but in `LHS := RHS`, for convenience it is okay to write it without `list`. The doc says "As long as j returns a list, each element of the list becomes a column in the resulting data.table. This is the default *enhanced* mode." ... but I'm not sure what "enhanced mode" refers to here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very good question that touches design decision about `:=` operator.

For simple calls using `:=` as an operator, like `col := val`, we decided to wrap `val` into a list automatically. This decision was made to make it more convenient for users to assign single column.

When you are using function call form, `":="(col = val)` we are not wrapping `val` into list anymore. It is extended form already. `:=` behaves as an alias to `list` but updating *in-place*. You can always check what will be the updated column by changing `:=` into `list` (or `.`) like `.(col = val)`.

Not that even when using `:=` as an operator, you still have to provide RHS as list of you are creating 2+ columns, `c("col1","col2") := list(val1, val2)`.